# A tuple of two generics constrained to the same parameterized type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to have a collection of tuples, where the first and second type are interrelated by their parameterized type. Specifically, something that looks like this:

```js
class Parent
{
    items: Map<number, [GenericOne<T = any>, GenericTwo<GenericOne<T>>]>
}
```

Obviously the above isn't correct, but I'm just trying to convey the idea. Map can have any tuple, as long as the first item is a GenericOne bound to anything, and the second item is thus constrained by the first to be GenericTwo of that. So for example, `[GenericOne<number>, GenericTwo<GenericOne<number>>]` and `[GenericOne<string>, GenericTwo<GenericOne<string>>]` are allowed, but not `[GenericOne<number>, GenericTwo<GenericOne<string>>]`. If I use "any" for both:

```js
class Parent
{
    items: Map<number, [GenericOne<any>, GenericTwo<GenericOne<any>>]>
}
```

I of course allow tuples I don't want, such as `[GenericOne<number>, GenericTwo<GenericOne<string>>]`. If I push the generic up to the parent class, then I constrain the Map to only *one* type:

```js
class Parent<T>
{
    items: Map<number, [GenericOne<T>, GenericTwo<GenericOne<T>>]>
}
```

And thus don't allow both `[GenericOne<number>, GenericTwo<GenericOne<number>>]` and `[GenericOne<string>, GenericTwo<GenericOne<string>>]` in the map. Is there a way to write this such that the second item infers the `T` from the first and uses the same one?

Comment: The solution to push `T` to the parent seems the most  reasonable.  At any given time the map will only be of one type.

Comment: This isn't the case for what I'm doing, the Map is in fact of many types. If it was of one type, i wouldn't be having to deal with this. This is a map of deferred constructor calls of a set of subclasses that all inherit from the same class. ParentClass[] allows different subclass members. This is a mapping to [Constructor, ConstructorArgs], which will later be called: calls.map([Constructor, args]) => new Constructor(args)).

Comment: To clarify the types, the actual types would be Map<KEY, [ConstructorType, ConstructorParameters<ConstructorType>]>. I can assemble this by hand just fine by manually typing out ConstructorPairs = [C1, ConstructorParameters<C1>] | [C2, ConstructorParameters<C2>] | ... So the types *do* work out once assembled. But I'd like a more concise way than listing out 30 combinations.